# For every partial order ≤ is the relation < transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

For every general partial order ≤ is the relation < := ≤ ∩ ≠ transitive

I tried working with the definition of the partial order.
A partial order is antisymmetric, transitive and reflexive.
The intersection of two sets is the set of the elements that contains all elements of A that also belong to B (or equivalently, all elements of B that also belong to A), but no other elements.

So the question is now, if the transitivity depends on the equality of the elements, and therefore the reflexitivity?

My guess would be that the statement can be true, but doesn't have to.

But I couldn't come up with a good counter example.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: If $a<b$ and $b<c$ then $a\leq b$ and $b\leq c$. So you know $a\leq c$. Now you just need to show $a\neq c$. What happens if $a=c$?

Comment: If $a=c$ then a < b and b < c can't be true, because there can't be a b to fulfill it, right? Otherwise we wouldn't have an partial order to begin with and because of the intersection with $\neq$ we don't have an a<c anyway for $a=c$. So the statement is true for all partial orders?
I'm not sure if I get it right..

Comment: You need to explain why "that can't be true." Right now, it is just hand-waving. What property of the partial order is violated if $a=c$.

Comment: If $a=c$, we have $a < b$ and $b < a$ which is only true if $a=b$ but exactly that contradicts the intersection with $a≠b$..
So antisymmetric is violated, correct?
I'm trying to think straight about it.. but I seem to go round in circles..